# @ForeignKey#name not working with @JoinTable @OneToOne mappings?

Tags: hibernate

I am using `Hibernate 5.4.10.Final` and tried to create bidirectional `@OneToOne` relation saved in `@JoinTable`. It works but I am unable to name foreign keys and end up with Hibernate's generated MD5s.

Consider there are 2 entities: `Email` and `Account`. They can have `@OneToOne` relation in join table `email_account`, mapped (owned) inside `Email` entity with:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable( name = "email_account",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(  name = "email_id",
                                        referencedColumnName = "id",
                                        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "`fk:email_account<is>email`")),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(   name = "account_id",
                                                referencedColumnName = "id",
                                                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "`fk:email_account<of>account`")),
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "`fk:email_account<is>email`"),
            inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "`fk:email_account<of>account`"))
private Account account;
```

Neither `@JoinTable.foreignKey`/`@JoinTable.inverseForeignKey`, nor `@JoinTable.joinColumns.foreignKey` work (tried each of them separately and together like above).

I've also tried applying Hibernate's old `@ForeignKey` onto field:

```
@OneToOne(...) // same as above snippet
@JoinTable(...) // same as above snippet
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(  name = "`fk:email_account<is>email`",
                                        inverseName = "`fk:email_account<of>account`")
private Account account;
```

In this case - `fk:email_account<is>email` will be created, but not the inverse. This annotation applied to owned side (`Account`) doesn't do anything.

Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong? Are there other solutions?

EDIT:

```
Hibernate: create table email_account (account_id bigint, email_id bigint not null, primary key (email_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table email_account add constraint FKbielrkd94qhlqshaoyu5wcom0 foreign key (account_id) references account (id)
Hibernate: alter table email_account add constraint FKm0rybu0s2dqc8qvhi0562w6av foreign key (email_id) references email (id)
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @SternK MySQL 8.0.12 (community). I don't think this is a DB problem as naming FK works in many other places using code syntax proposed in the post (this is the first case I can't configure).

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: Hibernate does not pick up your `@ForeingKey` declarations during db generation by the mapped model.

Comment: @SternK Yes, but seems that its only (so far) the case for exactly above situation - OneToOne with JoinTable. For example OneToOne with JoinColumn with ForeignKey works. ManyToMany with JoinTable with ForeignKey also works. Please note join column/table difference in my answers. EDIT: By works I mean FK itself and #name field.

Comment: One more question: what hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: @SternK org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect - Could dialect even affect how Hibernate generates mappings from JPA annotations? Have look at my edit at the end of the post - this is the output during generation it's the Hibernate that clearly specifies those MD5-format names.

Comment: Yes sure, dialect allows hibernate to generate appropriate sql for each particular database and DDL SQL can be very different from different databases.

Comment: @SternK This has to be Hibernate bug or lack of feature as I've tried other dialects. Unless someone has idea if I am doing something wrong I might report this (somehow...)